# How to pass node argument to a local task form?

Tags: forms, routes, 10

Suppose I have a route for a local task like this:

```
MODULE_NAME.node_options:
  path: '/node/{node}/options'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\MODULE_NAME\Form\NodeOptionsForm'
    _title: 'Options'
  requirements:
    _entity_access: 'node.update'
    node: \d+
  options:
    parameters:
      node:
        type: 'entity:node'
```

`NodeOptionsForm` shall present 2-3 radio buttons to the user to select a service to perform on the node, e.g. create a summary of the body using A.I.

a) Which base class should I use for the form?

b) How is the {node} argument actually passed to the form instance? Or in other words, how must the form instance be created in order to have access to the node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the NodeInterface class in your buildForm like below

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\MODULE_NAME\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;

/**
 * @internal
 */
class NodeOptionsForm extends FormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'make_special_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, NodeInterface $node = NULL) {
    // Node object will be in $node and you can perform your logic in this function.
    $form['#title'] = $node->label();
    $form['#node'] = $node;
    return $form;
  }
```

a) Which base class should I use for the form? => **FormBase class will be used for all basic forms unless it a config form.**

b) How is the {node} argument actually passed to the form instance? Or in other words, how must the form instance be created in order to have access to the node? => **You can pass it as NodeInterface $node in buildForm.**

Comment: Thank you so much. This isn't obvious until you learn about it from an example. The Drupal documentation is a bit challenging, if you come from different languages that use Doxygen, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Routes for local tasks do not have different requirements, compared to routes that are not used for local tasks, apart from being added in the *.links.task.yml* file for the module.

For example, the *Book* module define the following local task.

```yaml
entity.node.book_outline_form:
  route_name: entity.node.book_outline_form
  base_route: entity.node.canonical
  title: Outline
  weight: 2
```

The route is defined by these lines.

```yaml
entity.node.book_outline_form:
  path: '/node/{node}/outline'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: 'node.book_outline'
    _title: 'Outline'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer book outlines'
    _entity_access: 'node.view'
    node: \d+
  options:
    _node_operation_route: TRUE
```

In this case, the form is defined with `_entity_form`. It could have used  `_form` too; in that case, the `_form` value is the name (namespace included) of a class that implements [`FormInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormInterface.php/interface/FormInterface/10), which is implemented by the [`FormBase`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormBase.php/class/FormBase/10), a base class module can extend for their forms.
Other base classes that can be used for forms are [`ConfigFormBase`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21ConfigFormBase.php/class/ConfigFormBase/10), for configuration forms, [`ConfirmFormBase`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21ConfirmFormBase.php/class/ConfirmFormBase/10), for confirmation forms, or [`ImageEffectFormBase`](https://ImageEffectFormBase), for an image effect settings.

Any route parameters are passed to the `buildForm()` method any class that implements `FormInterface` needs to implement.

The alternative is doing like the Book module does, adding a new form class using [`hook_entity_build()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_type_build/10) and using `_entity_form` in the route definition.

```php
function book_entity_type_build(array &$entity_types) {
  /** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface[] $entity_types */
  $entity_types['node']->setFormClass('book_outline', 'Drupal\\book\\Form\\BookOutlineForm')
    ->setLinkTemplate('book-outline-form', '/node/{node}/outline')
    ->setLinkTemplate('book-remove-form', '/node/{node}/outline/remove')
    ->addConstraint('BookOutline', []);
}
```

In this case, the edited entity is passed in `$this->entity` to the methods of the entity form class.